# Lowest Upper Bound or Supremum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

How does following set have a supremum?

$$S = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left[-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right]$$

My doubt is that, since we are approaching $1$ from the right side there shouldn't be any supremum.

Comment: A set can't have more than one supremum (least upper bound), so why do you use the plural suprema (least upper bounds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $1$ is not a supremum (or even an upper bound) for any of the intervals you intersect doesn't stop it from being the supremum of the intersection as a whole.

The set $S$ is $[0,1]$. Plain and simple. The exact details of how we construct $S$ do not change which set we end up with. The nature of the boundary of $S$ at $1$ isn't "different" as a result of the intersections, and the same can be said about the boundary at $0$.

The set $[0,1]$ has supremum $1$ and infimum $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every subset of $\mathbb R$ that has an upper bound also has a supremum. Your set $S$ is bounded above, for example, $10$ is an upper bound for $S$. Therefore, $S$ has a supremum. You are therefore wrong.

---

To actually figure out what the supremum should be, first think about what it *cannot* be.

Can the supremum be $0.5$? Why not? Can it be $1.5$? Why not?

Comment: But we are approaching infinity from the right side.

Comment: @Al.A. What do you mean by "approaching infinity from the right side"?

Comment: Existence of an upper bound does not confirm the existence of Suprema in all cases.

Comment: @Al.A. The existence of an upper bound does indeed confirm the existence of supremum when we are talking about subsets of $\mathbb R$